# How to use Sony VAIO buttons to lock the screen?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, laptop, acpi

I have a Sony Vaio VPCEG laptop, [like this](https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3aANd9GcTrzOguqZF9evX_ARrJPCSUQp3jZLfM3ADb-LWAPJAb_c-a1WV3).

I'm using Lubuntu 11.10. I'd like to use those 3 buttons (Assist, WEB and VAIO). They work with Windows 7, to recover the system and to open the browser. But in Linux, they don't work.

How to set up them to lock the screen or to start the screen saver when pressed?